# denoise node not available under compositing in blender 2.8

Tags: compositing-nodes, denoise

I was following blender gurus new donut tutorial. after modelling the donut, i rendered it once, went into compositing to add a denoiser node to the rendered image. but if i search it, its not available. right now i have the render layers and composite nodes.

Comment: It's only available in 2.81. You can find it in the video's description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denoise node is only available in Blender 2.81. You can download the experimential builds [here.](https://builder.blender.org/download/)

Answer (score 0):

Go to compositor screen, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd> and type rendering layer in search

Comment: How is that related to denoising compositing node? That will only add render layer node. Note that the question is specifically for version 2.80, that node in compositing is available for versions since then which is in the answer

Comment: Well it works the same for denoising, you only have to add denoising nod too. Before you render the scene you have to turn on denoising option and that's all